# How to make sure images captured by FFMPEG from USB is lossless?

Tags: ffmpeg, images, v4l

I'm to capturing 10 images from camera. Like so:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vframes 10 -video_size 640x480 test%3d.jpg
```

[Since JPG is lossly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982409/is-jpeg-lossless-when-quality-is-set-to-100), at I need to change the image format. Let's say `tiff`. Like so:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vframes 10 -video_size 640x480 test%3d.tiff
```

Does this ensure, image files are lossless as we got from camera?

Or since It's using `-vframes 10` it works like a 10 frame video, and ffmpeg uses some video compression at each frame (making some information loss)?

/I'm sorry if this is a stupid question/

Comment: TIFF is a container format, and inside it could still be jpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solely depends on your source. Some cameras provide MJPEG/H.264 output, so it's hard to talk about "lossless" at all. Check `ffmpeg` output for more info.

I'm not entirely sure about TIFF (it has some compressed lossy forms AFAIK) but BMP and PNG formats are 100% lossless.

Another point to consider is that your camera even in lossless mode may provide YUV output which [doesn't translate](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/359657-If-I-convert-from-YUV-to-RGB-I-loss-quality) into RGB losslessly, so writing raw data could be more desireable.